# assembly 8086 adding a space in a string

Tags: string, assembly, space, x86-16

I ran into a problem in my program. Basically what i want to do check if there is a space after a dot in a string and if there isn't i add a space right after the dot. However i don't get how to go about this since my buffer is limited size, therefore if i add the space, the last letter of the buffer will be erased? or am i doing this wrong? thank you for the help in advance :)
   For example: Hello.Hi = Hello. Hi

```
MOV cx, ax
        MOV si, offset readBuf
        MOV di, offset writeBuf
      work:
        MOV dl, [si]
        CMP dl, '.'
        JE  dot
      increase:
        MOV [di], dl
        INC si
        INC di
        LOOP work
      dot:
        CMP dl+1, ' '
        JNE noSpace
        JMP increase
      noSpace:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code.  The first one is this line:

```
    CMP dl+1, ' '
```

This is adding 1 to the value in `dl` and comparing that to a space character which is not what you want.  What you want is to compare the next character, so you'll have to load it into a register with `MOV dl, [si]` or similar.

The second problem is algorithm.  It's often easiest to start with psuedo-code and then create the assembly language version from that.  For example:

1. load a character
2. is there room left?
3. if not, exit
4. if so, save the char
5. does char == period?
6. if not, go to 1
7. is there room left?
8. if not, exit
9. if so, save space char
10. load a character
11. does char == space?
12. if so, go to 1
13. if not, go to 2

Note that "load a character" means both fetching the character and incrementing `si`, and "save a character" means both saving the character and incrementing `di`.  Also note that steps 2, 3 and 4 are identical to steps 7, 8 and 9.  This suggests a potential for a subroutine or macro so that you only have to write (and debug!) the code once and can use it multiple times.